# Completely stumped at this reactjs logic, of a variable not updating the state of a component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, state, recharts

I am using `recharts`, and if the `data` variable is outside of a class, it works fine. What happens is it loads, animates the graph, and shows the "dot" coordinates. However, if the `data` variable is inside the class, it does not animate, and does not update the "dot" coordinates css.

Notice the commented out data in the render method, if I uncomment that, and comment out the top data variable, it doesn't work, but this current setup works just fine. Any ideas for a fix? I eventually want to load `this.props.data` instead of `data` once this is fixed.

```
const data = [{ name: '07/14/2017', mood: 6 }, { name: '07/15/2018', mood: 7 }];

class LinearGraph extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
    //const data = [{ name: '07/14/2017', mood: 6 }, { name: '07/15/2018', mood: 7 }];

    return (
      <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="80%">
        <LineChart
          data={data}
          margin={{ top: 5, right: 50, left: 0, bottom: 5 }}
        >
          <XAxis dataKey="name" />
          <YAxis />
          <CartesianGrid
            strokeDasharray="3 3"
            horizontal={false}
          />
          <Tooltip />
          <Legend />
          <Line
            type="monotone"
            dataKey="mood"
            stroke="rgba(43, 191, 217, 0.9)"
            dot={{ stroke: '#ff0000', strokeWidth: 12 }} // this isn't working at all
            activeDot={{ r: 1 }}
            strokeWidth={5}
          />
          <ReferenceLine y={7} label="Max" stroke="green" strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        </LineChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    );
  }

}
```

also for a more visual understanding, in this photo it's when it works (can't show the animation, but you can see the "dot" coordinates are working):

[image]

And here it's not working:
[image]

EDIT: I've also tried setting the state in componentWillMount (and componentDidMount but this latter gave a warning):

```
class LinearGraph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ data: this.props.data });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="80%">
        <LineChart data={this.state.data} />
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: You need to follow the React lifecycle, which will rerender on prop and state changes.  Can you define `data` as a property of your component's `state`?

Comment: If in the constructor I set this.state = { data: this.props.data}, it's undefined. now if I set it to be an empty array, I can't do this.setState({data: this.props.data}) in the render method, it throws tons of errors, and not sure where else I can set it due to the asynchronous loading. I can't make it a function in the class, and then call it in render for the same reason. @JordanBonitatis

Comment: I've also tried adding this.setState to componentWillMount and componentDidMount. It's bizarre because this.state.data is showing an empty array, and this.props.data is working just fine in the console logs within the methods, as it asynchronously updates.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track setting `initialState` in your constructor.  If the library doesn't like an empty array, can you initiate it as an array w/ a single empty object, like `data: [{}]`?  (Admittedly, w/o knowing the inner-workings of the library, that's a bit of a shot in the dark)

Comment: I completely agree with Jordan about React lifecycle. For the async data you need to use promise as shown by Kyle in his answer. When the data is fetched then the state will be set.

Comment: Hmmm, the parent component has a function that returns an async value, isn't part of reactjs's magic that it updates based on state, so no need to resolve a promise explicitly in child container? Just simply call the props, and when the prop is updated, it will set the state, which in turn updates?

Comment: Does `LinearGraph` have props value of data?  If so, you can directly pass it on the `LineChart`:  `<LineChart data={this.props.data} />`

Comment: @Kyle That was my original implementation, it shows the data, however it does not animate, and the "dot" coordinates are default white. See the two images I posted. On screen resize, it however then updates the "dot" coordinates to the appropriate red color.

Comment: @Kyle I even tried making the parent function return a promise, that resolves the data, and then in ComponentWillMount, I do this.props.data.then((data) => this.setState( { data }); but that didn't work either >_>

Answer (score 2):

`render` is called on state changes.  You need to brush up on the react [component's lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html).  Best practice is to declare your state then load it in a lifecycle `componentDidMount` function.

```
class LinearGraph extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data = []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Get your data here, from a const or an API
        fetch('api/get_data')
            .then(res => res.json()) // Get the json
            .then(res => this.setState({data: res.data})) // Consume the json
            .catch(err => alert('foo'));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <LineChart data={this.state.data} />
            </div>
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I was actually playing around with this before you posted. Would it be possible to have componentDidMount simply have this.setState({data: this.props.data}), as the fetch is occurring in the parent component and is passing data to other children as well? Because I tried and it didn't work

Comment: actually it's giving me a warning and saying "do not set state in component did mount"

Comment: This makes a lot more sense than my commented approach; I was assuming the `data` was static/hardcoded

Comment: Try `componentWillMount`

Comment: I tried both componentWillMount and componentDidMount. I just updated my original post in the bottom with an EDIT of the update. Still not working :(

Comment: You need to wrap your `setState` inside a `setTimeout` (or in my example--an AJAX call) if you want to do that.  Think about this: Setting the state immediately calls your render function.  So...?

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense actually. I assumed that part of reactjs magic is that when the prop updates, there's some inner function that then updates the state after setState. Is there a more elegant way to rerender once props updates from undefined to the data object?

Answer (score 0):

Woo, so the solution was to call `componentWillReceiveProps`, so I just added:

`componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.setState({ data: this.props.data });
}`

and it's now updating nicely, without the need for callbacks or promises

Comment: Welp, nevermind. this works for the initial load, but if I change pages on my site and come back, same problem. I see the graph line, but the dots do not update to appropriate css color.